# Refund payment from Paypal for android app

Tags: android, paypal

I have made an android app which uses Paypal as payment gateway. If due to some reason I want to refund back the amount to the user from my android app, how can I do that?

Comment: How to use this link in my android app ?                                                                      https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer Paypal developer documentation. There they have listed sample code to integrate. On sandbox.paypal.com you can create test account and test your integration. Sharing the link for sale refund below:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#sale_refund

Comment: what are the problems you are facing? Also which paypal API you were using for forward money movement..

Comment: I have used this link to build Paypal section in my app https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp/src/main/java/com/paypal/example/paypalandroidsdkexample/SampleActivity.java

Comment: How do I test the sale refund before implementing it?

Comment: do you just want to see if refund works for a transaction? If yes, then in sandbox just login as merchant. Select the transaction and from Action drop down select "Issue Refund"

Comment: I want a refund from my android app

Comment: I don't think the android app have the functionality to do refund. You will have to integrate with the rest apis to do refund.

Comment: How to use this link?https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: you should probably try to do rest integration instead of NVP integration. The link you have shared is for nvp integration which I would not recommend.